# Dalvik cannot find class inside external JAR through reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, http-post

I've been doing some reflection code for quite a while now, but only came to an issue lately because of the external JARs. The JARs in question here are those associated with HTTPPost http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html so that I can do a POST request

I use the same IDE Eclipse to code my Java code and the Android code in seperate projects.

In my Android project I have copied the JAR files into the /libs folder, and the JARs are added to Android Dependencies.

In the Java project I've added the dependencies within the IDE so that I do not get the coding errors popping up.

To 'compile' the Java project I use the following command lines

```
javac -classpath android.jar;httpclient-4.1.2.jar;httpcore-4.1.2.jar;httpmime-4.1.2.jar MyReflectionClass.java

jar -cf MyReflectionClass.jar MyReflectionClass.java

dx --dex --output=classes.dex myreflectionclass.jar
```

No errors reported.

These steps have always worked fine when I did not require external JARs, until now. It seems like the first line isn't enough to 'import' the JARs/annotations (I don't know these terms really well)

The Android project is able to load the class within the Java project, and the Java code executes until this line

```
MultipartEntity ent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

where I get this error in Logcat

```
tag = dalvikvm
text = Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity', referenced from method MyReflectionClass.mymethod
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the httpclient classes, the classes of httpmime are not part of Android. You need to supply them yourself (e.g. by putting them in the libs/ folder of your Android project).

Comment: I have already done that. I have included the HttpMime classes in both the libs folder of my Android project and my Java project's classpath

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. So the error occurs while running the packaged APK file on the device / emulator? Because from the description of your questions this it is not 100% clear and it sounds a bit like you are having the classes on the CP while compiling but not when executing. So just to be clear: Not only the myreflection.jar but also the httpmime.jar are in the libs/ folder of the Android project (respectively included in the APK)?

Comment: yes that is correct. If i had not included those jars in the CP then there would be compile errors, so I had that covered. I have also added the libraries into the /libs folder of my Android project, such that if I were to run the same exact code in say, an Android activity there will be no problems. I'm only getting the error at runtime now

Comment: Hm... sorry I have no real idea. Just one more question though: Why are you using `dx` when compiling your java project and what are you doing with the resulting `classes.dex` file? Is it possible to upload the project somewhere to have a look at it?